# Passing parameter to grails mapping

Tags: grails

I have named mapping I'm trying to pass a parameter to.  While I have googled/viewed many responses on this question when using the grails tag in a gsp:

```
<g:link mapping="accountDetails" params="[acctNumber:'8675309']">
```

I am trying to use `g.link` and not `<g:link` in my taglib and am getting an exception.  This is the line in my tag lib:

```
String otherProfileLink = g.link(mapping:"browseProfile", params:"['profileId':'123']", "my link text")
```

In my URLMappings:

```
 name browseProfile: "/browseProfile/$profileId" {controller = 'search'; action = 'show'}
```

The exception is:

```
Unable to create URL for mapping [/browseProfile/(*)] and parameters [{controller=message, action=index}]. Parameter [profileId] is required, but was not specified!
```

I've tried a few variations on the params value, with and without quotes, with/without closures.  But so far no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
g.link(mapping:"browseProfile", params: [profileId:'123']) { "my link text" }
```

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Blasted quotes.